# How do I answer the question "where do you work" at US Airport?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration

So I have a valid b1/b2 (visitor visa) and I've traveled multiple times to the US. I'm planning to go to the US for a vacation for a month before I head on to Canada. I have a sister in California with whom I plan to stay. Now the issue is this - during Customs and Immigration interviews, every time I was asked "where do you work" - I had a company and location to talk about. This time I've quit my job and I'm moving to Canada (haven't found a job yet). How should I answer the "where do you work" question without causing unnecessary alarm?

Comment: Don't lie. Have you already paid for tickets to Canada?

Comment: Yup... I have booked a ticket for canada for a month later. The problem is this - the last time I traveled into the US, it was at the beginning of this year; about 4 months after my last trip. I was asked so many questions (actually the same question in multiple ways) just because of the 4 month gap. Now if I were to say "between jobs" or "taking a break", I'm scared there'd be a secondary interview.

Comment: Answer that you do consulting work. This is typically understood as the cover story for the under employed.

Comment: @Maria that's why you should tell them the truth. You decided to leave your current job and move to Canada. To better prepare for the new challenges you decided to take a month of vaction and visit your sister - maybe a declaration from her that she'll cover your accomodation and expenses would be helpful? After that month you plan to go to proceed and go to Canada.

Comment: Do you have employment authorization in Canada? Just be honest and say you’re taking a break from work. Have proof of ample funds etc. That said know that you’re taking a risk.

Comment: I do, I have a work authorization for Canada, and I'd be carrying those papers too. I guess i'll also carry my bank statements/proof of funds.

Comment: Hi Maria, it's a non-issue.  Say you're from Germany (you don't say where you're from, we'll say Germany).  The fact is **you "work" in Germany**.  Am I right?  Look me in the eye and tell me "where you work".  Is it Japan?  Sydney?  Moscow?  Germany?  Of course, you **work in Germany**.  OK, maybe at the moment you're between contracts or whatever, so what.  You're German and you work, obviously, in Germany.   ***They just want to hear that you don't work IN THE USA - that's what they're getting at.***  Good luck!

Comment: @Fattie Some people are never able to tell even a white lie with a straight face.

Comment: I understand @MusoniusRufus , but it's not a lie.  OP "works in" Germany.  (if you happen to be unemployed that doesn't mean that's not the country you "work in".)

Comment: Thank you all for your responses! 
@Robokaren, if I do use the term consultant, I'm hoping they don't ask me for a company name

Comment: @Musionius Rufus Risk... have there been many cases where people haven't been allowed in? I thought that the worst case would be that I'd get a stamp for lesser than 6 month. And yes, I can't lie - a lot like Joey and the Raccoon :D

Comment: @Fattie, thanks for the response. I always assumed they also asked you about the company you worked in (not just location) as a sign that you're working somewhere?

Comment: @maria, anything can happen.  but in general they are just wanting to know (essentially) "where you live your life".   Sure, yours is a special case, you're literally moving to Canada.  You would literally just say **"I am moving to a new job in Canada"**.  Don't overthink it.  Be honest.  You'll be fine.

Answer (score 2):

I would be honest.  Say you work in Canada and right now are between jobs, and it seemed like a good time to visit your sister.